# One-to-many relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, one-to-many

I'm trying to create a One-to-many relationship in Django. In my example, I have a news post, which may have several images associated with it. However, different news posts will never share images.

As far as I can see, there are two ways to do this: Through a `ManyToManyField`, which creates a multi-select tool in the admin panel, which shows all the images ever uploaded, or through a `ForeignKeyField` in the `PostImage` class, which results in there not being any option to add new images when creating a new news post on the admin panel.

Since the users of the admin panel will not be at all technically-inclined, I would like two things, if possible:

- Add several images on the "Create new news post" page, without having any images from other news posts as a choice
- Less importantly, replace the multi-select box with checkboxes, or anything less confusing than a multi-select box.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second part is the easier one:
You want the [horizontal javascript filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)

If you go with a ManyToManyField, you could filter those choices by using a [Custom Manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers).

If you use a ForeignKey, you would want to use one of the [Admin Inlines](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). If you really never re-use images, use the inlines.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. I prefer the Manager solution. For anyone who needs it at a later stage, the documentation for Custom Managers is available at: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers